# Why does the mysqli bind function not handle my string correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

It took me like a month to figure out how make a session handler function work in PHP. I only had one problem, the `bind_param` function using `i` to fetch records instead of `s`.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT data FROM session WHERE  id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

This `$id` is a session id with contains numbers and letters like: `e5eeire57wjeuewq8w` Even if I have no records with this session, this query returns about 8 records in `num_rows`. So I solved this by putting a `s` instead of `i` in bind param.

My question here is, why does bind param treat my string like an integer? Why does it return 8 rows even if I had 0 rows with this id?

Comment: It's probably doing a cast, and a non-numeric string will result in 0 when cast to int (note, there are caveats to this e.g. when the string starts with a number).

Comment: oh, thank you for your answer. hard to believe that one i instead of s would give me days trying to make this function work...

Comment: @GabrielaDias Honestly, if you work with PHP long enough, you'll learn to stop being surprised by what PHP will allow in type conversion

Comment: @Machavity yeah, it makes my session insecure giving an user a random session... just because of this bind param. really need to pay attention in details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment on the [bind_param page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#102917) that confirms what Jon said in comments

> PHP will automatically convert the value behind the scenes to the underlying type corresponding to your binding type string.  i.e.:

```
$var = true;
bind_param('i', $var); // forwarded to Mysql as 1
```

Comment: thank you! I saw id and put an i... forgetting that it was a session id... so much trouble to solve this... a simple s make a lot difference.